# Why does running `f <- function(x){x} %>% f` not throw an error?

Tags: r, magrittr

R does not complain when one runs:

```
library(magrittr)
f <- function(x){x} %>% f
```

(but running `f(1)` throws a C stack error).

However, isn't it equivalent to:

```
f <- f(function(x){x})
```

which throws the error `f not found`?

Why does the first command not throw an error?

Answer (score 4):

`function` binds less strongly than the infix operator `%>%`. This means that your code is equivalent to

```
f <- function(x) ({x} %>% f)
```

And not to

```
f <- (function(x) {x}) %>% f
```

The latter does indeed raise the error you’re expecting.

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to :

```
f <- function(x) f(x)
```

and results in an infinite recursive call

Answer (score 2):

Ah I understand:

```
> body(f)
{
    x
} %>% f
```

In fact this is equivalent to `f <- function(x){{x} %>% f}`.